# Is it possible to return an associative container with a custom sort function?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, c++20

In a project of mine I have to to return a map with a custom sort-function from a function, however I don't know how I'm supposed to specify the return-type of said function.

A simplified example follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

std::map<std::string, bool> get_entries()
{
    auto cmp = [](const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
        { return (a.length() != b.length()? a.length() > b.length(): a < b); };

    std::map<std::string, bool, decltype(cmp)> entries;
    entries.insert({"Mom", true});
    entries.insert({"Dad", false});
    entries.insert({"Sister", true});
    entries.insert({"Brother", true});
    entries.insert({"Child", false});

    return entries;
}


int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, bool> entries(get_entries());

    for (auto& [key, value]: entries)
        std::cout << "Key: " << key << ", value: " << (value? "true": "false") << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This code does not compile since I need to specify *something* about the lambda-function.

Is this possible, and how would I go about this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: _"since I need to specify something about the lambda-function."_ What's the exact error message? [Edit] your question and add that information please!

Comment: `auto get_entries()`, `auto entries{get_entries()};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: stop using lambdas like that. Make your custom sort function an actual type, since it is a clear part of your interface:

```
struct custom_sort
{
    bool operator() const (const std::string& a, const std::string& b)
    {
      return (a.length() != b.length()? a.length() > b.length(): a < b);
    };
};

std::map<std::string, bool, custom_sort> get_entries()
{
    std::map<std::string, bool, custom_sort> entries;
    entries.insert({"Mom", true});
    entries.insert({"Dad", false});
    entries.insert({"Sister", true});
    entries.insert({"Brother", true});
    entries.insert({"Child", false});

    return entries;
}
```